# Probability of Getting a number on throwing a dice.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is that what is the probability of getting the number 6 when throwing a 6 sided die.

Since 6 will either come or it won't the probability of this event should be 0.5.

How come the answer is 1/6 then?

Seriously how do you counter this argument?

Comment: "If I buy a lottery ticket  either I win or I lose, so I must have a $50\%$ chance of winning!"

Comment: Yeah, what's the problem with that? I know that the question is silly.

Comment: Just because there are only two cases does not mean they are equally likely.

Comment: @lulu Yup that looks correct. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To try to answer your question, and your comment 'what is the problem with my Sample Space of 6 and not 6?':

You can have a sample space of '6 and not 6', but these two outcomes are not equally likely.  This is an important point: Not all sample spaces have equally likely outcomes.

When probabilities are assigned to outcomes in a discrete sample space, two rules must be obeyed (to suit the definition of a probability distribution): Every individual outcome probability must be a real number between $0$ and $1$ inclusive; and the sum of the outcome probabilities must equal $1$.  Anything that fits these two conditions is a probability distribution on the sample space.  However, to be most useful, we select a probability distribution that will best reflect reality.  Assigning 6 and not 6 each a probability of $\frac12$ will likely not reflect reality very well at all (in the sense that it is highly unlikely that in the long term half your rolls will come up $6$--assuming that your die is fair).

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: +1 It's actually this answer that makes me *understand* the problem of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

On a six sided dice there are 6 possible outcomes, rolling a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. Rolling a 6 is only one of these possible outcomes and so the probability of it happening is $\frac 16$

Comment: Yeah I know that. But what's the problem with my argument??

Comment: I've just explained that, there are 6 outcomes and you want the probability of getting one of them. If you wanted the probability of getting an even number,the answer would be $\frac 36 = \frac 12$ because there are 3  even numbers you can roll from a possible 6

Comment: But what is the problem with my Sample Space of 6 and not 6?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

probability is the ratio of possible outcome to possible event, in this question possible events are six, and they are mutually exclusive, and you have to count them all, when I am saying one is not possible, that is happening in 5 separate events, not one, the logic is (6)U(5)U(4)U(3)U(2), they can not happen in same time so you have to consider OR here.